# I Lost My Build

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I set my spawnpoint accidentally far away from my creations in minecraft and am wondering if there's any way to find it and get back, some command? Or something that will do this? Also the world is completely flat if that helps any. Pls help worked hard on these builds!

Comment: Which are you trying to get back—the spawn point or your creations? I’m just trying to understand your question better.

Answer (score 3):

Use [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/). This program will let you search your world for specific blocks, so you can search for a block you've used in your buildings that doesn't spawn naturally in your world. The program will find these blocks for you and can tell you their coordinates, so you can find them again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to get back relatively quickly, but mabye if you copied that world and go into it, the spawnpoint goes back to default, so you could hit F3 write down the X Y Z then go back to the original and tp or fly walk run ect to that location